# No module names 'src' when importing from parent folder in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, import, jupyter-notebook

I have the following folder structure in my project

```
my_project
  notebook
    |-- some_notebook.ipynb
  src
    |-- preprocess
        |-- __init__.py
        |-- some_processing.py
    __init__.py
```

Now, inside `some_notebook.ipynb` I simply want to get the methods from `some_processing.py`. Now we I run

```
from src.preprocess import some_processing
```

from `some_notebook.ipynb` it always throws

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

I found multiple questions regarding this and played around with `sys.path.append(<path-to-src>)`. But I couldn't solve it. Which path do I provide? Something like `../src` didnt work?

I checked for example the [AlphaFold project from DeepMind](https://github.com/deepmind/alphafold/blob/main/notebooks/AlphaFold.ipynb) and they are using it also with this structure. I tried to replicate exactly like they did.

How can I solve this? Which path do I provide in `sys.path.append()`?

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. Running

```
sys.path.insert(1, os.path.join(sys.path[0], '../src'))
```

made it possible to import anything from parent module `src`.

Answer (score 1):

Adding path to your `src/` directory into the `sys.path` is OK, but import should be like this: `from preprocess import some_processing`.

Off-topic 1: I'm using the same project structure. So this is usually the first cell of my average jupyter notebook:

```py
%reload_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2

import sys
import os.path as osp

SRC_SUBDIR = '../src/'
SRC_SUBDIR = osp.abspath(SRC_SUBDIR)
if SRC_SUBDIR not in sys.path:
    print(f'Adding source directory to the sys.path: {SRC_SUBDIR!r}')
    sys.path.insert(1, SRC_SUBDIR)
```

Off-topic 2: In this case, as `src` is not needed in import statement, you don't need the file `src/__init__.py`.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/your/project')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also otherwise change the working dir for notebooks in VSCode settings:

```json
"jupyter.notebookFileRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src"
```